# Function return [Object Object] not the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, odoo

I created this function and I don't know why it return `[Object Object]` and not the value that I got. The function should return a string like `(Main/121)`. However, the alert shows the value that I wanted.

```
module.Order = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function (attributes) {
            Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            this.pos = attributes.pos;
            var that = this;
            this.sequence_number = this.pos.pos_session.sequence_number++;
            debugger;
            this.uid = this.generateUniqueId();
            this.pro = this.get_the_other_main();
            this.set({
                creationDate: new Date(),
                orderLines: new module.OrderlineCollection(),
                paymentLines: new module.PaymentlineCollection(),
                name: _t("Order ") + this.uid,
                client: null,
                sales_person: null,
                sales_person_name: null,
                new_id: this.pro
            });
            this.selected_orderline = undefined;
            this.selected_paymentline = undefined;
            this.screen_data = {};  // see ScreenSelector
            this.receipt_type = 'receipt';  // 'receipt' || 'invoice'
            this.temporary = attributes.temporary || false;
            return this;
        },
      get_the_other_main: function (callback) {
           return new instance.web.Model("pos.order").call('get_the_product', []).done(
                 function(results) {
                    var result = results.toString().split(',');
                     var stringsl=result[1];
                     var thenum = stringsl.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
                     var sasa=parseInt(thenum,10)+1
                     var zika=('00' + sasa).slice(-4)
                     var the_str=result[1].slice(0,-4).toString();
                     var new_seq_sasa=the_str+zika
                     alert(new_seq_sasa)
                     return callback(new_seq_sasa);
                }

            );
        },
```

Comment: Looks like an asynchronous call which means, you can not return from it.

Comment: then how could i get the value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `callback` argument and change how you invoke your function:

```
get_the_other_main: function (callback) {
           return new instance.web.Model("pos.order").call('get_the_product', []).done(
                 function(results) {
                    var result = results.toString().split(',');
                     var stringsl=result[1];
                     var thenum = stringsl.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
                     var sasa=parseInt(thenum,10)+1
                     var zika=('00' + sasa).slice(-4)
                     var the_str=result[1].slice(0,-4).toString();
                     var new_seq_sasa=the_str+zika
                     alert(new_seq_sasa)
                     return callback(new_seq_sasa);
                }

            );
        },
```

Instead of:

```
this.pro = this.get_the_other_main();
```

Use (I refactored your code from comment):

```
var that = this;
this.get_the_other_main(function (result) {
  that.pro = result;
});
```

Comment: That's probably a promise returned, he should work with the promise instead of regressing to callbacks.

Comment: sorry i can't understand that what should i replace :( could you explain more ? what do you mean by obj.get_the_other_main(function (result) and  i try your code and still get [Object Object ]

Comment: Show code where do you actually use that function, where you call `get_the_other_main()`.

Comment: this.pro = this.get_the_other_main(); line like this.

Comment: Please Anyone Could help me i still get the same value :(